# I cannot compile using pca 9539 library

Tags: arduino

I was trying to to find a library for  NXP PCA9539PW IC, but the one i found it's either outdated and i'm not able to fix it or i couldn't find another.

I need to control 11 inputs using this IC, i already soldered pull up resistors for each of them but I cannot make my IDE to compile using the following library.

I currently struggle with : https://github.com/AD0ND/PCA9539 (i know it's for esp but on pull requests somebody made some modifications that might work). I couldn't make it work on my arduino uno.

Can you guys please suggest me how to make it work or if it's another library available ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's terrible library, it seems they renamed files from clsPCA9539.* to PCA9539.* and forgot to change include. You'll have to change `#include "clsPCA9539.h"` to `#include "PCA9539.h"` in file PCA9539.cpp

Next thing are A0-A7 and B0-B7 definitions in file PCA9539.h are colliding with Arduino's analog input aliases and B* are even worst as they are #defines. You can either change those, or just use 0..15 directly. Eg:

```
enum {
    A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7,
    B0, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7
};
```

to:

```
enum {
    PCA_A0, PCA_A1, PCA_A2, PCA_A3, PCA_A4, PCA_A5, PCA_A6, PCA_A7,
    PCA_B0, PCA_B1, PCA_B2, PCA_B3, PCA_B4, PCA_B5, PCA_B6, PCA_B7
};
```

And in the example use those new aliases:

```
ioport.pinMode(PCA_A0, OUTPUT); // instead of A0
```

After those changes the library will be compilable on Uno (but I don't have any PCA9539, so I can't test it)

EDIT: I completely forgot they have also constructor completely wrong:
`PCA9555::PCA9555(uint8_t address) {` should be `PCA9539::PCA9539(uint8_t address) {`

Comment: Thank you for your time to look over the code and make the changes. Sadly, it's still not working. I receive: ' PCA9539-master/PCA9539.h:64:1: error: multiple types in one declaration' during compiling. I think you don't need a physical IC to replicate error, this library it's too outdated and buggy. Anyway thank you,

Comment: I finally managed to make this whole thing work. The problem was a semicolon missing after enum {} in the pca9539.h :) I have tested it and it's working great now, Thank you for your help. Now i'm looking forward to use 2 chips on same arduino, i assume this won't be hard as chips are using different i2c addresses.